# Libcurl example - No such file error

Tags: libcurl

i am working with libcurl in C and am getting an error "curl.h: No such file or directory" while executing make command in linux. So can you help me out.. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your include directory is missing the libcurl include files. What OS are you running `make` on and how did you install libcurl?

Comment: Am running on Linux Fedora and i install libcurl with          ./config

Comment: Try running `sudo yum install curl-devel` (I believe that is the redhat package: I'm a debian person myself so I'm not precisely sure what the curl development package is called on Redhat).

Answer (score 0):

Install Libcurl in windows visual studio. It is more simpler approach.